# Letter arrangement problems

Tags: combinatorics

Define a 'word' to be any distinct rearrangement of the letters.

(a) How many words can be created from AAAABBBCCDE (4 A's, 3 B's, 2 C's, 1
D, 1 E)?

(b) How many words contains no B's next to each other?

(c) How many words contain the D before the E?

---

The only way I can think of is to start counting the number of possible choices from a 1 letter word to a 11 letter word, which seems horrifying.

Comment: Have you learnt "$n$ choose $r$", or written as "$C^n_r$" or "$\begin{pmatrix}n\\r\end{pmatrix}$"?

Comment: I think they are asking you to use all letter while creating words.

Comment: yes I have. ...

Comment: @King Tut that sounds too good to be true.

Comment: I agree with King Tut.  (1) If you didn't have to use all letters I think they would have said "any distinct rearrangement of **some of** the letters.  (2) If you don't have to use all letters then part (c) doesn't make sense because a word might not contain a D or an E.  They could have said "...contain **a** D before **an** E", but they didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part a the answer simply goes as $\frac {11!}{4!3!2!}$

For the second part, first try arranging all the A's, C's,  D and E in $\frac {8!}{4!2!}$ and then select any three gaps ( for the B's to be placed)  between any two letters of the formed arrangement( note that you can also select the word starting and ending with B itself).  Hence the answer to second part becomes $\frac {8!}{4!2!}* \binom {9}{3}$.

For the third part the probability that D comes before E is simply $\frac {1}{2}$ of the total arrangements. 
Hence answer to third becomes 
$\frac {11!}{4!3!2!*2}$

Comment: For the second part, I think it's asking no B's to be placed next to each other. That is, ABBCB... would be invalid. I think?

Comment: @B.Li I had chosen three  places for  B's in the second part using  dashed places given in the arrangement _ A _ A _ A _ A _ C _ C _ D _ E _.  So how would two B's remain consecutive in this arrangement?

Comment: @B.Li First permute all letters except the dashed places.  And then place the B's on the dashed places in suitable way.

Comment: @B.Li No problem and you are welcome