# Permutation of alike objects

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Number of permutations of AAABBBCCC such that no two A's or B's or C's together

Comment: What was your approach?

Comment: A question mark was already too much?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Maybe of interest https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2632310/letter-arrangement-problems

Comment: I tried inclusion exclusion principle.  Assumed 3 sets X Y and Z..where X is atleast 2 A's together! Similar sets Y and Z... but that is getting too messy to solve!

Comment: Apparently a solution to this already exists! Apologies for bad manners! New to community...